# laplacian equation notation Evans

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation, laplacian

[image]

I am wondering what does $\Delta_x \Phi(x-y)$ really mean?
I come cross the claim that $\Delta_x \Phi(x-y)=\Delta_y \Phi(x-y)$. I am hoping anyone could help me explain that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write
$$
\Delta_x \Phi(x-y)=\Delta \Phi(\cdot-y)(x)
$$
or
$$
\Delta_x \Phi(x-y)=\Delta F(x) ,
$$
where
$$
F(x) = \Phi(x-y) .
$$

Comment: Thank you! Also, for the other part of the question, do we just prove it by direct computation(using chain rule)?

Comment: @000000000: Yes, if it was one derivative the sign would change. Then two derivatives give you the sam sign.